# reorder_within not working with specific columns when facet wrapped

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, facet

I have an object with engagement data of various members of congress, grouped by year and categorized by party and office. I am extracting from it the top number of engagements by year and ordering it accordingly with the code below.

```
test <- OfficeRaw %>%
  filter(!is.na(id)) %>%
  count(`Year`,`MoC Name`,`Party Label`, `Congressional Entity`) %>%
  filter(`Party Label` != "Indipendent") %>%
  slice_max(order_by = n,by=Year, n=10) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(`MoC Name`=reorder_within(`MoC Name`, n, Year))
```

Which creates the dataset I am providing here.

```
structure(list(Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("2019", 
"2020", "2021", "2022", "2023"), class = "factor"), `MoC Name` = structure(c(56L, 
52L, 44L, 38L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 18L, 19L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 44L, 29L, 
32L, 35L, 65L, 64L, 61L, 53L, 57L, 37L, 20L, 53L, 26L, 31L, 63L, 
58L, 55L, 50L, 51L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 46L, 30L, 33L, 34L, 36L, 60L, 
62L, 59L, 54L, 40L, 41L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 27L, 28L, 43L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L), levels = c("Debbie Stabenow___2023", "Dick Durbin___2023", 
"Jake LaTurner___2023", "Jim McGovern___2023", "Joni Ernst___2023", 
"Marco Rubio___2023", "Mitch McConnell___2023", "Raphael Warnock___2023", 
"Robert Aderholt___2023", "Sherrod Brown___2023", "Tom Kean___2023", 
"Colin Allred___2023", "Cory Booker___2023", "Earl Blumenauer___2023", 
"John Boozman___2023", "Mike Braun___2023", "Sara Jacobs___2023", 
"Cory Booker___2019", "Dean Phillips___2019", "Dean Phillips___2020", 
"Gregory Meeks___2022", "Hal Rogers___2022", "Jackie Walorski___2022", 
"Jeff Merkley___2019", "Jim Costa___2019", "Jim McGovern___2020", 
"Jim Risch___2022", "Joaquin Castro___2022", "K. Michael Conaway___2019", 
"Karen Bass___2021", "Lois Frankel___2020", "Marco Rubio___2019", 
"Marco Rubio___2021", "Michael McCaul___2021", "Roger Marshall___2019", 
"Sara Jacobs___2021", "Betty McCollum___2020", "Chrissy Houlahan___2019", 
"Darin LaHood___2021", "Darin LaHood___2022", "Earl Blumenauer___2022", 
"Gregory Meeks___2021", "Jeff Merkley___2023", "Jim McGovern___2019", 
"Jim McGovern___2021", "Joaquin Castro___2021", "Pat Roberts___2019", 
"Ted Lieu___2019", "Todd Young___2019", "Betty McCollum___2021", 
"Cory Booker___2021", "Ilhan Omar___2019", "Jackie Walorski___2020", 
"Bob Casey___2022", "Earl Blumenauer___2021", "John Boozman___2019", 
"Xochitl Torres Small___2020", "Grace Meng___2021", "Sara Jacobs___2022", 
"Betty McCollum___2022", "Darin LaHood___2020", "Grace Meng___2022", 
"Jackie Walorski___2021", "Bob Casey___2020", "Earl Blumenauer___2020"
), class = "factor", scores = structure(c(`Betty McCollum___2020` = 6, 
`Betty McCollum___2021` = 7, `Betty McCollum___2022` = 10, `Bob Casey___2020` = 11, 
`Bob Casey___2022` = 8, `Chrissy Houlahan___2019` = 6, `Colin Allred___2023` = 4, 
`Cory Booker___2019` = 5, `Cory Booker___2021` = 7, `Cory Booker___2023` = 4, 
`Darin LaHood___2020` = 10, `Darin LaHood___2021` = 6, `Darin LaHood___2022` = 6, 
`Dean Phillips___2019` = 5, `Dean Phillips___2020` = 5, `Debbie Stabenow___2023` = 3, 
`Dick Durbin___2023` = 3, `Earl Blumenauer___2020` = 13, `Earl Blumenauer___2021` = 8, 
`Earl Blumenauer___2022` = 6, `Earl Blumenauer___2023` = 4, `Grace Meng___2021` = 9, 
`Grace Meng___2022` = 10, `Gregory Meeks___2021` = 6, `Gregory Meeks___2022` = 5, 
`Hal Rogers___2022` = 5, `Ilhan Omar___2019` = 7, `Jackie Walorski___2020` = 7.5, 
`Jackie Walorski___2021` = 10, `Jackie Walorski___2022` = 5, 
`Jake LaTurner___2023` = 3, `Jeff Merkley___2019` = 5, `Jeff Merkley___2023` = 6, 
`Jim Costa___2019` = 5, `Jim McGovern___2019` = 6, `Jim McGovern___2020` = 5, 
`Jim McGovern___2021` = 6, `Jim McGovern___2023` = 3, `Jim Risch___2022` = 5, 
`Joaquin Castro___2021` = 6, `Joaquin Castro___2022` = 5, `John Boozman___2019` = 8, 
`John Boozman___2023` = 4, `Joni Ernst___2023` = 3, `K. Michael Conaway___2019` = 5, 
`Karen Bass___2021` = 5, `Lois Frankel___2020` = 5, `Marco Rubio___2019` = 5, 
`Marco Rubio___2021` = 5, `Marco Rubio___2023` = 3, `Michael McCaul___2021` = 5, 
`Mike Braun___2023` = 4, `Mitch McConnell___2023` = 3, `Pat Roberts___2019` = 6, 
`Raphael Warnock___2023` = 3, `Robert Aderholt___2023` = 3, `Roger Marshall___2019` = 5, 
`Sara Jacobs___2021` = 5, `Sara Jacobs___2022` = 9, `Sara Jacobs___2023` = 4, 
`Sherrod Brown___2023` = 3, `Ted Lieu___2019` = 6, `Todd Young___2019` = 6, 
`Tom Kean___2023` = 3, `Xochitl Torres Small___2020` = 8), dim = 65L, dimnames = list(
    c("Betty McCollum___2020", "Betty McCollum___2021", "Betty McCollum___2022", 
    "Bob Casey___2020", "Bob Casey___2022", "Chrissy Houlahan___2019", 
    "Colin Allred___2023", "Cory Booker___2019", "Cory Booker___2021", 
    "Cory Booker___2023", "Darin LaHood___2020", "Darin LaHood___2021", 
    "Darin LaHood___2022", "Dean Phillips___2019", "Dean Phillips___2020", 
    "Debbie Stabenow___2023", "Dick Durbin___2023", "Earl Blumenauer___2020", 
    "Earl Blumenauer___2021", "Earl Blumenauer___2022", "Earl Blumenauer___2023", 
    "Grace Meng___2021", "Grace Meng___2022", "Gregory Meeks___2021", 
    "Gregory Meeks___2022", "Hal Rogers___2022", "Ilhan Omar___2019", 
    "Jackie Walorski___2020", "Jackie Walorski___2021", "Jackie Walorski___2022", 
    "Jake LaTurner___2023", "Jeff Merkley___2019", "Jeff Merkley___2023", 
    "Jim Costa___2019", "Jim McGovern___2019", "Jim McGovern___2020", 
    "Jim McGovern___2021", "Jim McGovern___2023", "Jim Risch___2022", 
    "Joaquin Castro___2021", "Joaquin Castro___2022", "John Boozman___2019", 
    "John Boozman___2023", "Joni Ernst___2023", "K. Michael Conaway___2019", 
    "Karen Bass___2021", "Lois Frankel___2020", "Marco Rubio___2019", 
    "Marco Rubio___2021", "Marco Rubio___2023", "Michael McCaul___2021", 
    "Mike Braun___2023", "Mitch McConnell___2023", "Pat Roberts___2019", 
    "Raphael Warnock___2023", "Robert Aderholt___2023", "Roger Marshall___2019", 
    "Sara Jacobs___2021", "Sara Jacobs___2022", "Sara Jacobs___2023", 
    "Sherrod Brown___2023", "Ted Lieu___2019", "Todd Young___2019", 
    "Tom Kean___2023", "Xochitl Torres Small___2020")))), `Party Label` = c("Republican", 
"Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat", 
"Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", 
"Democrat", "Democrat", "Republican", "Republican", "Republican", 
"Democrat", "Democrat", "Republican", "Republican", "Democrat", 
"Democrat", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat", 
"Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", 
"Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", 
"Republican", "Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", 
"Democrat", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat", 
"Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat", 
"Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Republican", "Republican", 
"Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat", 
"Republican", "Republican", "Republican", "Democrat", "Republican", 
"Democrat", "Republican"), `Congressional Entity` = c("Senate", 
"House", "House", "House", "Senate", "House", "Senate", "Senate", 
"House", "Senate", "House", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "House", "Senate", "House", "House", "House", "Senate", 
"Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "House", "House", "House", 
"House", "Senate", "House", "House", "House", "House", "House", 
"Senate", "House", "House", "House", "House", "House", "Senate", 
"House", "House", "House", "House", "House", "Senate", "House", 
"Senate", "House", "Senate", "House", "Senate", "Senate", "House", 
"Senate", "Senate", "House", "House", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
"Senate", "House", "Senate", "House"), n = c(8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 13L, 11L, 10L, 
10L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -68L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have been trying to create a descending horizontal graph that will order this list of top ten engagements by year, using the code below:

```
test %>%
ggplot(aes(n,`MoC Name`, fill = `Party Label`), stat = "identity") +
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~Year, scales = 'free_y') +
  scale_y_reordered()
```

Which results in this:

[image: ImageOutput]

The graph is out of order and I have been trying to reorder those odd columns for a while to no avail, using fct_inorder, changing the position of reorder_within, and even falling back to the older reorder function. I am not sure how I can fix the issue at this point.

Any help or redirection to relevant information is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you grouped by a fourth variable aka `Congressional Entity` when computing the counts. As a consequence you have some duplicated pairs of `MoC Name` and `Year` for which `reorder_within` can not account for:

```
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

# Duplicates

test |> 
  count(Year, `MoC Name`) |> 
  filter(n > 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Year  `MoC Name`                 n
#>   <fct> <fct>                  <int>
#> 1 2019  Jim Costa___2019           2
#> 2 2019  Jim McGovern___2019        2
#> 3 2020  Jackie Walorski___2020     2
```

To fix that drop `Congressional Entity` when computing the counts, i.e. do

```
count(`Year`,`MoC Name`,`Party Label`)
```

As I don't have your raw data the reprex below uses the already wrangled data to achieve the same result. That's why I had to add `wt = n` to compute the counts based on the counts in the wrangled data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidytext)

test1 <- test |>
  mutate(`MoC Name` = gsub("_.*$", "", `MoC Name`)) |>
  count(`Year`, `MoC Name`, `Party Label`, wt = n) |>
  mutate(`MoC Name` = reorder_within(`MoC Name`, n, Year))

test1 |>
  ggplot(aes(n, `MoC Name`, fill = `Party Label`), stat = "identity") +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~Year, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. It also seems that the data itself did not distinguish MoCs that were engaged in two different Congressional Entitites, so that was further creating a problem. I removed the Congressional Entity parameter and it worked as you've shown. For future reference, is there a way to maintain columns using `count()` or would we have to manually put them back in once the code is run. For instance, if I didn't have the problem I mentioned at the start, I wouldn't have simply done a `left_join()` with a list indicating wheter my MoC is in the House or the Senate. Is that efficient?

Comment: Hej Mike. I see. Now I understand why you added the fourth variable to `count()`. The issue is that the "duplicated" `MoC`s were members of both House and Senate in the same year. If that wasn't the case, adding a fourth (or ...). variable would not have resulted in an issue when using `count`. IMHO a left_join is valid option. But still you have to make sure that for each pair of `MoC` and year you have a unique assignment to either House or Senate. A second option would of course be to remove one of the duplicates (i.e. keep the House or the Senate obs but not both) before doing your count.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be with the ordering of the `MoC Name` variable within each facet. You can use the `fct_reorder` function from the forcats package to explicitly specify the order of the `MoC Name` within each facet. Also, you can use `coord_flip` to create a horizontal bar plot.

Try this modified code and see if it produces the desired output:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

test %>%
  mutate(`MoC Name` = fct_reorder(`MoC Name`, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, `MoC Name`, fill = `Party Label`), stat = "identity") +
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~Year, scales = 'free_y') +
  scale_y_reordered() +
  coord_flip()
```

In this code, `fct_reorder` is used to reorder `MoC Name` based on the `n` variable within each facet. The `coord_flip` function is used to create a horizontal bar plot. This should result in a plot where the bars are ordered within each facet according to the `n` variable.